# How to apply display: flex and flex-direction: row in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to apply `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` with the following code:

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const listItem = document.getElementById("myList");
  const fruits = ["Banana", "Papaya", "Mango", "Lemon"];

  for (let fruit of fruits) {
    let list = document.createElement("li");
    list.textContent = fruit;
    list.classList.add("dcode");
    listItem.appendChild(list);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Set the `style=""` attribute. Also, your `listItem` and `list` variables are named the wrong-way-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the styles to the parent element that you have selected:

```js
listItem.style.display = 'flex';
listItem.style.flexDirection = 'row'
```

You can also assign them all at once:

```js
listItem.style.cssText = "display: flex; flex-direction: row";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a .style for the list item elements parent and assign some cssText for display. In my example I use `.style.cssText`

```js
const listItem = document.getElementById("myList");
const fruits = ["Banana", "Papaya", "Mango", "Lemon"];

for (let fruit of fruits) {
  let list = document.createElement("li");
  list.textContent = fruit;
  list.classList.add("dcode");
  listItem.appendChild(list);
  listItem.style.cssText = 'display: flex; flex-direction: row; list-style-Type: none;'
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```